# Error while deploying to Wildfly 10

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10

When i deployed to wildfly 10 server , i am getting the following error.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1)                                   WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]): java.lang.IllegalStateE                                  xception: WFLYDR0006: Directory /usr/share/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/67 is not                                   writable
        at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.validateDir(Con                                  tentRepository.java:314)
        at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.getDeploymentHa                                  shDir(ContentRepository.java:291)
        at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.getDeploymentCo                                  ntentFile(ContentRepository.java:282)
        at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepository$Factory$ContentRepositoryImpl.addContent(Cont                                  entRepository.java:225)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentFullReplaceHandler.addFromContentAdditionParam                                  eter(DeploymentFullReplaceHandler.java:205)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentFullReplaceHandler.execute(DeploymentFullRepla                                  ceHandler.java:125)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.j                                  ava:890)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext                                  .java:659)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationCont                                  ext.java:370)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java                                  :1344)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:39                                  2)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:217)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:748)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:742)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3$1.run(ModelControllerImpl.java:742)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Schedul                                  edThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThrea                                  dPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Comment: Do you have write access to `/usr/share/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/67`?

Comment: It's quite obvious: ```Directory /usr/share/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/67 is not writable```